# SharePoint Online: Default value: + Calculated Value option Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint Online, I have a list with various columns.

In the list, there is a column name 'Change Type' which has few dropdown menu. One of the option in the dropdown menu in 'Project'

Another column named 'Complexity' also has dropdown menu and one of the option is 'N/A'

In 'Complexity' column I want to use Default value: + Calculated Value. I want the Default Value to be 'N/A' if in 'Change Type' column, someone selects 'Project'.

I have tried this formula and it didn't work and I get Unexpected error message.

```
=IF([Change Type]=”Project”,”N/A”)
```

What formula should I use?

Comment: Your posted formula has curly quotes. Try using straight quotes.  `=IF([Change Type]="Project","N/A")`

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online,  it's not supported that formula contains reference to other fields when setting column default value. Only caculated column can cotain other columns.

If you are using modern experience, you could use column formatting to achieve this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting